# OpenGL frame buffer slow and spontaneously stalls. Can even cause a system crash when used extensively

Tags: python, performance, opengl, framebuffer, fbo

Apparently frame buffers are fast and the best way to render offscreen to textures or to simply pre-create things.

My game however is not liking them at all. In the current code frame buffers are used often, sometimes each frame, several times. When used the game begins to slow down but not instantly. It seems to take time (Perhaps a built-up memory problem?). In some areas the frame buffer objects do not seem to slow the game down much accept occasionally the game will stall for a few seconds before continuing as normal.

I assume the Frame buffers are the problem because the game is fast in areas where they aren't used.

I'm using python with pyopengl. The OpenGL code is similar to the code in other language so I do not think python knowledge is significantly important.

Some things are rendered directly to the screen, other textures are rendered to other textures which is involved with the Surface class. This resembles pygame which is what I begun my game in before I changed my mind.

Here is the relevant code.

```
def create_texture(surface):
surface.texture = glGenTextures(1)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadIdentity() #Loads model matrix
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, surface.texture) #Binds the current 2D texture to the texture to be drawn
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR) #Required to be set for maping the pixel data
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR) #Similar as above
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, surface.surface_size[0], surface.surface_size[1], 0, GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface.data) #Put surface pixel data into texture
if surface.data == None:
    setup_framebuffer(surface)
    c = [float(sc)/255.0 for sc in surface.colour] #Divide colours by 255 because OpenGL uses 0-1
    if surface.background_alpha != None:
        c[3] = float(surface.background_alpha)/255.0
    glClearColor(*c)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    end_framebuffer()
Surface.texture_ready.append(surface)


   def setup_framebuffer(surface):
    #Create texture if not done already
    if surface.texture == None:
        create_texture(surface)
    #Render child to parent
    if surface.frame_buffer == None:
        surface.frame_buffer =  glGenFramebuffersEXT(1)
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, surface.frame_buffer)
    glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, surface.texture, 0)
    glPushAttrib(GL_VIEWPORT_BIT)
    glViewport(0,0,surface._scale[0],surface._scale[1])
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity() #Load the projection matrix
    gluOrtho2D(0,surface._scale[0],0,surface._scale[1])
def end_framebuffer():
    glPopAttrib()
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity() #Load the projection matrix
    gluOrtho2D(0,1280,720,0) #Set an orthorgraphic view
    def draw_texture(texture,offset,size,a,rounded,sides,angle,point):
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity() #Loads model matrix
    glColor4f(1,1,1,float(a)/255.0)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture)
    if rounded == 0:
        if angle == 0:
            glBegin(GL_QUADS)
            glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0)
            glVertex2i(*offset) #Top Left
            glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0)
            glVertex2i(offset[0],offset[1] + size[1]) #Bottom Left
            glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0)
            glVertex2i(offset[0] + size[0],offset[1] + size[1]) #Bottom, Right
            glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0)
            glVertex2i(offset[0] + size[0],offset[1]) #Top, Right
            glEnd()
        else:
            glBegin(GL_QUADS)
            glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0)
            glVertex2f(*rotate_coordinate(offset,point,angle)) #Top Left
            glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0)
            glVertex2f(*rotate_coordinate((offset[0],offset[1] + size[1]),point,angle)) #Bottom Left
            glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0)
            glVertex2f(*rotate_coordinate((offset[0] + size[0],offset[1] + size[1]),point,angle)) #Bottom, Right
            glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0)
            glVertex2f(*rotate_coordinate((offset[0] + size[0],offset[1]),point,angle)) #Top, Right
            glEnd()
    else:
        global arc_factors
        arc = [[o*rounded for o in c] for c in arc_factors]
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
        if sides % 2:
            for c in arc:
                coordinates = (offset[0] + rounded - c[0],offset[1] + rounded - c[1])
                glTexCoord2f((coordinates[0]-offset[0])/size[0],(coordinates[1]-offset[1])/size[1])
                glVertex2f(*coordinates)
        else:
            glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0)
            glVertex2f(*rotate_coordinate(offset,point,angle)) #Top Left
        if sides % 4 > 1:
            for c in arc[::-1]:
                coordinates = (offset[0] + size[0] - rounded + c[0],offset[1] + rounded - c[1])
                glTexCoord2f((coordinates[0]-offset[0])/size[0],(coordinates[1]-offset[1])/size[1])
                glVertex2f(*coordinates)
        else:
            glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0)
            glVertex2f(*rotate_coordinate((offset[0] + size[0],offset[1]),point,angle)) #Top, Right
        if sides % 8 > 3:
            for c in arc:
                coordinates = (offset[0] + size[0] - rounded + c[0],offset[1] + size[1] - rounded + c[1])
                glTexCoord2f((coordinates[0]-offset[0])/size[0],(coordinates[1]-offset[1])/size[1])
                glVertex2f(*coordinates)
        else:
            glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0)
            glVertex2f(*rotate_coordinate((offset[0] + size[0],offset[1] + size[1]),point,angle)) #Bottom, Right
        if sides > 7:
            for c in arc[::-1]:
                coordinates = (offset[0] + rounded - c[0],offset[1] + size[1] - rounded + c[1])
                glTexCoord2f((coordinates[0]-offset[0])/size[0],(coordinates[1]-offset[1])/size[1])
                glVertex2f(*coordinates)
        else:
            glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0)
            glVertex2f(*rotate_coordinate((offset[0],offset[1] + size[1]),point,angle)) #Bottom Left
        glEnd()
def texture_to_texture(target,surface,offset,rounded,rotation,point):
    #Create texture if not done already
    if surface.texture == None:
        create_texture(surface)
    #Render child to parent
    setup_framebuffer(target)
    draw_texture(surface.texture,offset,surface._scale,surface.colour[3],rounded,surface.rounded_sides,rotation,point)
    end_framebuffer()
def texture_to_screen(surface,offset,rotation,point):
    if surface.texture == None:
        create_texture(surface)
    draw_texture(surface.texture,offset,surface._scale,surface.colour[3],surface.rounded,surface.rounded_sides,rotation,point)
    class Surface():
    texture_ready = []
    def __init__(self,size,extra = None):
        self._offset = (0,0)
        self.children = []
        self.blitted = False
        self.last_offset = [0,0]
        self.surface_size = list(size)
        self.colour = [0,0,0,255]
        self.data = None
        self.rounded = 0
        self.parent = None
        self.parent_offset = (0,0)
        self.texture = None
        self.frame_buffer = None
        self._scale = size
        self.background_alpha = None
        self.rounded_sides = 0
    def blit(self,surface,offset,rotation = 0,point = (0,0)):
        texture_to_texture(self,surface,offset,surface.rounded,rotation,point)
        if surface not in self.children:
            self.children.append(surface)
        if surface.parent_offset != offset or not surface.blitted:
            surface.parent_offset = offset
            surface._offset = [offset[0] + self._offset[0],offset[1] + self._offset[1]]
            surface.recursive_offset_change() #Add to the children's offsets
            surface.blitted = True
    def set_background_alpha(self,alpha):
        self.background_alpha = float(alpha)/255.0
    def recursive_offset_change(self):
        for child in self.children:
            child._offset = (self._offset[0] + child.parent_offset[0],self._offset[1] + child.parent_offset[1])
            child.recursive_offset_change()
    def get_offset(self):
        return self._offset
    def fill(self,colour):
        colour = list(colour)
        if len(colour) < 4:
            colour.append(255)
        self.children = []
        self.textures = []
        self.colour = colour
        if self.texture != None:
            glDeleteTextures([self.texture])
            self.data = None
            create_texture(self)
    def get_size(self):
        return self.surface_size
    def get_width(self):
        return self.surface_size[0]
    def get_height(self):
        return self.surface_size[1]
    def round_corners(self,r,sides = 15):
        self.rounded = r
        self.rounded_sides = sides
    def get_rect(self):
        return Rect(self._offset,self.surface_size)
    def scale(self,scale):
        self._scale = scale
        return self
    def __del__(self):
        if self.texture != None:
            glDeleteTextures([self.texture])
        if self.frame_buffer != None:
            glDeleteFramebuffersEXT(1, [int(self.frame_buffer)])
class Game(Surface):
    game_size = None
    first_screen = None
    screen = None
    fs = False #Fullscreen false to start
    clock = None
    resize = True
    game_gap = None
    game_scaled = (0,0)
    title = None
    fps = -1
    enter_fullscreen = False
    exit_fullscreen = False
    scale_to_screen = False
    iconify = False
    on_focus_fullscreen = False
    f_key = False
    fade = 0
    p_key = False
    music_stop = False
    unfade = False
    event_after_fade = -1
    loaded = False
    fade = 255
    unfade = True
    homedir = os.path.expanduser("~")
    fade_screen = False
    keys = []
    events = []
    sections = []
    back_key = False
    transfer_args = ()
    mouse_pos = (0,0)
    def __init__(self,title,game_size,on_exit = sys.exit):
        self.keys = [False] * 323
        self.events = []
        pygame.font.init()
        pygame.mixer.init()
        self.title = title
        self.game_size = game_size
        self.first_screen = (1280,720) #Take 120 pixels from the height because the menu bar, window bar and dock takes space
        glutInit(sys.argv)
        glutInitWindowPosition(0,0)
        glutInitWindowSize(*game_size)
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA)
        glutGameModeString("1280x720:32@60") #720 HD
        glutCreateWindow(title)
        glutSetIconTitle(title)
        self.callbacks()
        self.game_gap = (0,0)
        self.on_exit = on_exit
        self.mod_key = 1024 if sys.platform == "darwin" else 64
        Surface.__init__(self,game_size)
        self.screen_change = True
        self.frames = [time.time()]
        self.fps = 60
        self.last_time = 0
        self.fade_surface = Surface([1280,720])
    def callbacks(self):
        glutReshapeFunc(self.reshaped)
        glutKeyboardFunc(self.keydown)
        glutKeyboardUpFunc(self.keyup)
        glutSpecialFunc(self.specialdown)
        glutSpecialUpFunc(self.specialup)
        glutDisplayFunc(self.game_loop)
        glutIdleFunc(self.game_loop)
        glutMouseFunc(self.mouse_func)
        glutPassiveMotionFunc(self.mouse_move)
        glutMotionFunc(self.mouse_move)
        glViewport(0,0,self.first_screen[0],self.first_screen[1]) #Creates the viewport which is mapped to the window
        glEnable(GL_BLEND) #Enable alpha blending
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) #Enable 2D Textures
        glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH) #Enable antialiased polygons
        glHint(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST)
        glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST)
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity() #Load the projection matrix
        gluOrtho2D(0,1280,720,0) #Set an orthorgraphic view
    def add_section(self,section_object):
        self.sections.append(section_object)
    def mouse_func(self,button, state, x, y):
        self.events.append((state,button,x,y))
    def mouse_move(self,x,y):
        self.events.append((MOUSEMOTION,x - self.mouse_pos[0], y - self.mouse_pos[1]))
        self.mouse_pos = (x,y)
    def keydown(self,char,x,y):
        #300 miliusecond delay, 50 milisecond repeat
        self.change_keys(char,True)
    def keyup(self,char,x,y):
        self.change_keys(char,False)
    def change_keys(self,char,bool):
        char = ord(char)
        #Switch backspace and delete
        if char == 8:
            char = 127
        elif char == 127:
            char = 8
        self.keys[char] = bool
    def specialdown(self,char,x,y):
        if char == GLUT_KEY_UP:
            self.keys[K_UP] = True
        if char == GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
            self.keys[K_DOWN] = True
        if char == GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
            self.keys[K_LEFT] = True
        if char == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
            self.keys[K_RIGHT] = True
    def specialup(self,char,x,y):
        if char == GLUT_KEY_UP:
            self.keys[K_UP] = False
        if char == GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
            self.keys[K_DOWN] = False
        if char == GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
            self.keys[K_LEFT] = False
        if char == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
            self.keys[K_RIGHT] = False
    def reshaped(self,w,h):
        #Scale game to screen resolution, keeping aspect ratio
        self.screen_change = True
        self.game_scaled = get_resolution((w,h),self.game_size)
        glutReshapeWindow(*self.game_scaled)
        glViewport(0,0,self.game_scaled[0],self.game_scaled[1])
        glutPositionWindow((1280- w)/2,(720 - h)/2)
    def game_loop(self):
        self.section.loop()
        if self.unfade:
            if self.fade == 255:
                play_music(self.section.music)
            if self.fade > 0:
                self.fade -= 5
            else:
                self.music_stop = False
                self.unfade = False
        if self.fade_screen and not self.unfade: #Fade out
            if self.fade == 0:
                sound("/sounds/menu3/fade.ogg").play()
                self.music_stop = True
                pygame.mixer.music.fadeout(850)
            if self.fade < 255:
                self.fade += 5
            else:
                self.fade_screen = False
                self.unfade = True
        if self.fade_screen == False:
            if self.event_after_fade != -1:
                self.section = self.sections[self.event_after_fade]
                self.section.transfer(*self.transfer_args)
                self.transfer_args = ()
                self.event_after_fade = -1
        self.fade_surface.fill((0,0,0,self.fade))
        self.blit(self.fade_surface,(0,0))
        for event in self.events:
            if event[1] == MUSICEND and self.music_stop == False:
                play_music(self.section.music)
        self.events = [] #Remove events
        global draw_texture_time
        #Updates screen properly
        for event in self.events:
            if event.type == QUIT:
                self.on_exit()
        if True:
            if self.keys[K_f]:
                if self.f_key == False:
                    self.f_key = True
                    if self.fs == False:
                        self.enter_fullscreen = True
                    else:
                        self.exit_fullscreen = True
            else:
                self.f_key = False
        if self.on_focus_fullscreen and pygame.display.get_active():
            self.on_focus_fullscreen = False
            self.enter_fullscreen = True
        pixel_data = []
        if self.enter_fullscreen or self.exit_fullscreen:
            for surface in Surface.texture_ready:
                if surface.texture != None:
                    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, surface.texture)
                    glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,surface.data)
                    surface.texture = None
                if surface.frame_buffer != None:
                    pixel_data.append((surface,None))
                    glReadPixels(0,0,surface.surface_size[0],surface.surface_size[1],GL_BGRA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,pixel_data[-1][1])
            Surface.texture_ready = []
        if self.enter_fullscreen:
            glutEnterGameMode()
            self.callbacks()
            self.fs = True
            self.enter_fullscreen = False
        elif self.exit_fullscreen:
            glutSetCursor(GLUT_CURSOR_INHERIT)
            self.fs = False
            glutLeaveGameMode()
            self.callbacks()
            self.exit_fullscreen = False
            if self.iconify:
                self.on_focus_fullscreen = True
        if self.enter_fullscreen or self.exit_fullscreen:
            for surface, data in pixel_data:
                surface.frame_buffer =  glGenFramebuffersEXT(1)
                setup_framebuffer(surface)
                glDrawPixels(surface.surface_size[0],surface.surface_size[1],GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,data)
                end_framebuffer()
        if self.iconify:
            pygame.display.iconify() #Minimise
            self.iconify = False
        glFlush()
        glutSwapBuffers() #Flip buffer
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        self.frames.append(time.time())
        time_d = (self.frames[-1] - self.frames[-2])
        if time_d < 0.01667:
            time.sleep(0.01667 - time_d)
            self.frames[-1] = time.time()
        self.fps = len(self.frames)/(self.frames[-1] - self.frames[0])
        if self.fps > 60:
            self.fps = 60
        self.frames = [frame for frame in self.frames if (self.frames[-1] - frame) < 1]
        glutSetWindowTitle(self.title + " - " + str(int(self.fps)) + "fps")
    def blit(self,surface,offset,rotation = 0,point = (0,0)):
        if surface.get_offset() != offset or not surface.blitted:
            surface._offset = offset
            surface.recursive_offset_change() #Add to the children's offsets
        surface.blitted = True
        texture_to_screen(surface,offset,rotation,point)
    def transfer_section(self,section,args=()):
        self.transfer_args = args
        self.event_after_fade = section
        self.fade_screen = True
```

Bravo if anyone can help me with this. I spent ages getting the FBOs to work at all. It's so frustrating that they aren't working properly. If it comes to removing them, it's a nightmare all over again. But I must face whatever needs to be done to make the game fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't worked with OpenGL for about 14 years so I'm not much help with that. I'm just looking at the Python code. There's a few things you can do to clean the code up, like use ".width" instead of ".surface_size[0]". You do have a get_width(), but descriptors are your friends. You also have checks for "if self.data == None" but there's no place where the .data field is ever set to anything besides None. Oh, and a minor point - the better form of this test is "if self.data is None".

I'm going on the assumption that you're running out of some sort of resource. I tried to follow the glBindTexture/glDeleteTexture logic but it confused me. Why do you store all your pending surfaces into the class variable Surface.texture_ready list? That is, why isn't it an instance variable?

Your game loop goes through and glBindTexture:s the texture_ready elements, then resets the list to []. But only when entering/exiting full-screen mode. If you don't go to full screen, it seems that texture_ready gets longer and longer.

You might consider using one of the profiling tools to see where most of the time is being spent. Even something as simple as [watching the line trace](http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2005/04/20/tracing_python_code.html) might be enough for you to spot where the slowdown is.

I'm afraid this isn't much help though, as I just don't know OpenGL.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. data is assigned on another function which I didn't think was necessary to show which is used to use images as textures.

I think that texture_ready thing is there to store textures which have been created so I can loop though them to be redrawn when entering fullscreen mode. Fullscreen mode doesn't work at the moment. I think the frame buffer issue is a bigger one right now. I need to store it as a class variable because it applies for all the instance's textures.

I will need to remove the surfaces I delete from the texture_ready list, you are correct, thank you...

Comment: I cant use profiling tools because they dont work with GLUT. Very annoying. I may have to revert to a pygame window, I don't know. I think GLUT might be messing up the threads.

I might take a look at that trace tool.

For now I am going to look at the thread problem and after I will look into the fullscreen before going back to this issue again.

Thank you again.

Comment: It seems the problem wasn't thread related. I'm moving onto the fullscreen now...

Comment: Mmm, I haven't done much with profiling in threads. In fact, I haven't done anything. As I recall, you need to set up a single profiler per thread, which make profiling some threading models very complicated. At this point all I can suggest is to start commenting out code until the problem disappears. And to wish you "Good Luck!"